# Lazy load tall images are being outstretched or cropped

Tags: javascript

The images are being outstretched vertically sometimes being cropped vertically.

If I try not to set height of `.ratio__content` the images gets under-lapped of the other images

[See Actual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIPlH.jpg)

(it's height is actually tall to realize the outstretch or crop)

```css
body {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.ratio {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.ratio:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: calc((9/16) * 100%);
}

.ratio__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio"><img class="ratio__content lazyload" data-src="https://binazizcorp.com/download.jpg"></div>
<div class="ratio"><img class="ratio__content lazyload" data-src="https://binazizcorp.com/1606279905.jpg"></div>
<div class="ratio"><img class="ratio__content lazyload" data-src="https://binazizcorp.com/1606279905.jpg"></div>
<div class="ratio"><img class="ratio__content lazyload" data-src="https://binazizcorp.com/1606279905.jpg"></div>
<div class="ratio"><img class="ratio__content lazyload" data-src="https://binazizcorp.com/1606279905.jpg"></div>

<div class="ratio"><img class="ratio__content lazyload" data-src="https://picsum.photos/1600/900?image=9"></div>
<div class="ratio"><img class="ratio__content lazyload" data-src="https://picsum.photos/1600/900?image=10"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/lazysizes@4.0.1/lazysizes.js"></script>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you not use `position: relative` instead?

Comment: I am checking the whole code again and again and forget this thing!. It is working now